# Mysql: Order by like?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, sql-like

assume that we are performing search using keywords: keyword1, keyword2, keyword3

there are records in database with column "name":

```
1: John Doe
2: Samuel Doe
3: John Smith
4: Anna Smith
```

now Query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (name LIKE "%John%" OR name LIKE "%Doe%")
```

it will select records: 1,2,3 (in this order)
but i want to order it by keyword
in example `keyword1=John, keyword2=Doe`
so it should be listed by keywords: 1,3,2 (because i want to perform search for "Doe" after searching for "John")

I was thinking about `SELECT DISTINCT FROM (...... UNION .....)`
but it will be much easier to order it somehow in another way (real query is really long)

are there any tricks to create such order?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
order by case 
    when name LIKE "%John%" then 1 
    when name LIKE "%Doe%"  then 2 
    else 3 
end
```

Comment: one more thing - if I understand it properly every LIKE will be executed 2 times in whole query?

Comment: @dfens: I am guessing that the `LIKE` in the `ORDER BY` clause will execute only on the data that was matched by the `WHERE` clause, so should be quicker.

Answer (score 6):

To build on RedFilter's answer, you could make the rows that have both keywords to be at the top:

```
order by case 
when (name LIKE "%John%" and name LIKE "%Doe%") then 1 
when name LIKE "%John%" then 2
when name LIKE "%Doe%"  then 3
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Read up on [Boolean Fulltext Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html), with which you can do ordering.

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT * 
 from
 (
  SELECT u.*, 1 OrderNum 
  FROM users 
  WHERE (name LIKE "%John%")
  UNION 
  SELECT u.*, 2 OrderNum 
  FROM users 
  WHERE (name LIKE "%Doe%")
  )
  Order by OrderNum
```

Answer (score -1):

My example will Order all of the `John`'s Alphabetically followed by the `Doe`'s.

```
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN name LIKE "John%Doe" THEN CONCAT('a',name)
    WHEN name LIKE "John%"    THEN CONCAT('b',name)
    WHEN name LIKE "%Doe"     THEN CONCAT('c',name)
    ELSE name  
END
```