# MySQL "Order By" query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the select query with `or` logical operator like following:

```
SELECT * FROM grabli_new.product where article like '%AV2%' or article like '%AV22%';
```

I need to ordering result set by "length of like pattern"(rows that contains the longest pattern in my case `'%AV22%'` must be in the beginning of result set). The query must return all result that contains `'%AV22%'` pattern in the beginning and only then all result that contains `'%AV2%'` pattern. Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql: Order by like?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609166/mysql-order-by-like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use something like this:

```
SELECT *, case when article like '%AV22%' 
                    then 1 
                    when article like '%AV2%' 
                    then 2 end orderIndex 
FROM grabli_new.product 
where article like '%AV2%' or article like '%AV22%'
order by orderIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to count (multi-byte) characters, use the CHAR_LENGTH function instead:

```
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH( column )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM grabli_new.product 
WHERE article LIKE '%AV2%' OR article LIKE '%AV22%' 
ORDER BY char_length(article) DESC
```

Comment: That won't work! The length of the pattern matters, not the length of the article itself.

Comment: what would u do by '0AV220' and '1AV210'?

Comment: @DirkNM : Legnth calculation will be done only for articles post filtered resultset.

Comment: @Mikhalil : I have used Char_Length() instead of length().

Comment: @knkarthikck24: Doesn't change anything. That's not what the OP want. And by the way, thats not your original answer that I commented.