# IF ELSE mysql query for LIKE operator

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query like this.

```
SELECT item FROM items WHERE catid=3 AND tag LIKE '%".$tag[1]."%' OR tag LIKE '%".$tag[2]"%' LIMIT 4
```

How can I tell mysql to search item those have `tag LIKE '%".$tag[1]."%'` first, before it continue the search process to find items those have `tag LIKE '%".$tag[2]."%'`. Because right now it looks like mysql randomly choose what condition to execute. Sometimes it displays 4 results that all are match `tag LIKE '%".$tag[2]."%'` which is I don't want to. I want mysql to prioritize `tag LIKE '%".$tag[1]."%'` first.

Comment: It is kind of unclear question can you please explain for better understanding.

Comment: @Mr.Developer I would like to tell Mysql to find items those have `tag LIKE '%tag1'` condition first before trying to find items those have `tag LIKE '%tag2%'` condition. Is it possible for doing that using mysql query or I need to do that from php?

Comment: `LIKE` is boolean operator, which is either `TRUE` or `FALSE` (or `NULL`) - it can't be `< 4`. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Do you mean get the first 3 (or 1 or 2 if there are less than 3) results for tag1 and the rest from tag2 from your data source in your result set?

Comment: @Mr.Developer P.Salmon I have refined the question. Please have a look. Thanks guys!

Comment: @zoora Can you try below my answer it is working same as you have mentioned in the question after edit.

Comment: @Mr.Developer um sorry I have refined the question again, the tag is actually an php array

Comment: @zoora Okay  this array `$tag[1]` and `$tag[2]` has some value like `tag1` and `tag2` ?

Comment: no `$tag[1]` and `$tag[2]` could be `lion` and `tiger`

Comment: You cannot mix bits of mysql and php like this. If you know PHP use that. To clarify your question you should publish sample data and expected results based on the sample data. You should also add a php tag to attract the attention of the php community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609166/mysql-order-by-like)

```
SELECT item FROM items WHERE catid=3 AND 
   (tag like '%".$tag[1]."%' or tag like '%".$tag[2]."%') order by case 
       when tag like '%".$tag[1]."%' then 1 
       when tag like '%".$tag[2]."%' then 2 
       else 3 
   end 
LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort the result so try below

```
WHERE catid=3 AND `tag` LIKE '%tag%' ORDER BY IF( `tag` LIKE 'tag1%',0, IF( `tag` LIKE '%tag2', 1, 2 ) )
```

Comment: Surely you won't have any tag2 records?

Comment: @P.Salmon I am sorry what do you means?

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes i have edited, but you comment is correct. Thank you for your notice +1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this using union with a limit for tag1

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from items;
+--------+--------+--------+----------+-----------+
| ITMSTK | ITMQTY | ITMCOG | ITMURN   | ITMSOU    |
+--------+--------+--------+----------+-----------+
| WN778  | 1      |      2 | 12345112 | WEB       |
| WN776  | 1      |      1 | 12345112 | WEB       |
| WN771  | 1      |      2 | 12345112 | WEB       |
| WN845  | 1      |      1 | 22544548 | ADVERT    |
| WN846  | 1      |      1 | 22544548 | ADVERT    |
| WN845  | 1      |     20 | 44848643 | TELEPHONE |
+--------+--------+--------+----------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> (SELECT itmsou FROM items WHERE 3=3 AND itmsou LIKE '%web%' limit 2)
    -> union all
    -> SELECT itmsou FROM items WHERE 3=3 AND itmsou LIKE '%advert%'
    -> ;
+--------+
| itmsou |
+--------+
| WEB    |
| WEB    |
| ADVERT |
| ADVERT |
+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I have refined my question please have a look thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take a look at below:

```
select *
   ,case when tag  like '%$keyword1%' then 1
        when tag   like '%$keyword2%' then 2 
    end as [priority]
from table_name
where tag   like '%$keyword1%'  or tag   like '%$keyword2%' 
order by [priority]
```

This actually still gives you the result of keyword2 but at same time it prioritized the keyword1 at the top.

Alternatively you maybe interested in sorting by "relevance" instead of your wild card search.

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45093695

Comment: that one only return keyword 1 result if is found while mine is actually using both keyword 1 and keyword 2 but sorting the result putting result using keyword 1 at the top