# Multiple Select Statement in MariaDB MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following sql statement and its working fine to a certain extent in that if possible would like to make it better and also get a total of all the selects at end row. I also tried to make the WHERE in one statement but was not able it did not return the order I have done below.

Thanks & Regards

```
SELECT  
    coalesce(account, ' ') AS Account,
    sum(gl.credit - gl.debit) AS Balances
    FROM `tabGL Entry` AS gl 
    WHERE account LIKE 'INC%'
    GROUP BY account WITH ROLLUP
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    coalesce(account, ' ') AS Account,
    sum(gl.debit - gl.credit) AS Balances
    FROM `tabGL Entry` AS gl
    WHERE account LIKE 'DCOI%'
    GROUP BY account WITH ROLLUP
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    coalesce(account, ' ') AS Account,
    sum(gl.debit - gl.credit) AS Balances
    FROM `tabGL Entry` AS gl
    WHERE account LIKE 'DMC%'
    GROUP BY account WITH ROLLUP
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    coalesce(account, ' ') AS Account,
    sum(gl.debit - gl.credit) AS Balances
    FROM `tabGL Entry` AS gl
    WHERE account LIKE 'INFC%'
    GROUP BY account WITH ROLLUP
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    coalesce(account, ' ') AS Account,
    sum(gl.debit - gl.credit) AS Balances
    FROM `tabGL Entry` AS gl
    WHERE account LIKE 'IDEX%'
    GROUP BY account WITH ROLLUP
```

To clarify the results required

```
Inc item 1 ---- 100
Inc item 2 ---- 100
 Inc Total ----  200
DCOI item 1 ---- 100 
DCOI item 2 ---- 100 
 DCOI Total ----  200
DMC item 1 ---- 100 
DMC item 21 ---- 100 
 DMC Total ----  200
Total Inc-(DCOI+DMC+INFC+IDEX)
```

Comment: Try to reorganise your data so that you can use '=' instead of 'LIKE'

Comment: `order by case when account LIKE 'INC%' then 1 when ... when account LIKE 'IDEX%' then 5 end`

Answer (score -1):

You can use OR with multiple Like operator

```
  SELECT  
        coalesce(account, ' ') AS Account,
        sum(gl.credit - gl.debit) AS Balances
        FROM `tabGL Entry` AS gl 
        WHERE 
        account LIKE 'INC%'
        OR  LIKE 'DCOI%'
        OR  account LIKE 'DCOI%'
        OR account LIKE 'DMC%'
        OR account LIKE 'INFC%'
        OR account LIKE 'IDEX%'
        GROUP BY account WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I actually did try that as well and while I got the result it was not in the order that I needed it to be.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609166/mysql-order-by-like this answer may help

Comment: If this is to work, it requires a little more thought