# Make a Dropdown list sort by number

Tags: php, html, dropdown

I made a dropdown menu and tried to list it.
But the list in the db doesn't start with "H01" so my dropdown starts with "H40"

How can I replace the code:

```
like 'H%'
```

[Code and Frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X559r.png)

Comment: You can add at the end of the query `order by EventCode ASC` maybe that would work

Comment: thank you :) it worked!

Comment: I think below link may helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609166/mysql-order-by-like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add order by your_column_name ASC in your query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add order_by to your select query.

For example

```
<?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `status` ORDER BY `status`.`status` ASC";
?>
```

Here status field has values like
H01, H02, H03, ... H10